# How to mount an old HFS System 7 Macintosh floppy with write access?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, mount, apple, floppy

I have an old 3.5" HD floppy disk. It was formatted on a Macintosh SE/30 and thus it is formatted with the HFS (not HFS+!) file system. I am having trouble mounting it properly. I have hfsutils and hfsprogs (though I think this is only for HFS+) installed. When putting the disk into my USB floppy drive and rebooting my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, the disk is mounted, but I can't write to it because it is in read-only mode. Removing and reinserting it will cause it to not be mounted automatically at all.

I tried mounting it manually with explicit rw, but I still can't write to it, only read:
sudo mount -t hfs -o rw /dev/sdb /media/andreas/xyz/

Answer (score 0):

It appears, though I'm not sure that hfsutils only allows traditional mounting in read only mode. Please correct me if I'm wrong about that, but for now this is the less convenient workaround I found: https://linux.die.net/man/1/hfsutils

hfsutils comes with a set of commands for managing files etc. on HFS partitions.